# WPF animation coefficient

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use some WPF double animation to move `StackPanel`.

```
<Canvas  ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <StackPanel  Name="tbmarquee" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

Every time I use the same time 30 seconds and I put different amount of `UIElemnts` under `StackPanel`. So the width of `StackPanel` is different and it changes the animation speed like if I have a lots of items under `StackPanel` then animation is very slowly and if I have 1 item it is very fast.

Any clue which **coefficient** I have to use *to get stable animation speed*?

Thank you!

P.S.

It seems that this code gives  more or less correct coefficient

```
var coeff = 0;

 if (test.Count >= 1 && test.Count <= 10)
        coeff = 60;
 else if (test.Count > 10 && test.Count <= 20)
        coeff = 120;
 else if (test.Count > 20 && test.Count <= 30)
       coeff = 240;
 else if (test.Count > 30 && test.Count <= 40)
        coeff = 300;
else if (test.Count > 40 && test.Count <= 50)
       coeff = 350;
else if (test.Count > 50 && test.Count <= 60)
        coeff = 400;
else if (test.Count > 60 && test.Count <= 70)
         coeff = 450;
 else if (test.Count > 70 && test.Count <= 80)
     coeff = 500;
else if (test.Count > 80 && test.Count <= 90)
    coeff = 530;
else if (test.Count > 90 && test.Count <= 100)
    coeff = 560;
and etc...
```

Any clue how to convert it into some expression?

Comment: could it be an idea changing the DesiredFrameRate? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.desiredframerate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Having less Animated visuals with the same animation `Duration` will cause the animation to appear much faster on screen. You should instead vary the 'Duration` taking into account the number of, in this case, elements that you will animate.

Answer (score 0):

Well... If someone need the answer then it is here.

I found the formula and coefficient.

```
var coeff = StackPanel.Children.Count * 3;
```

so I use it to animate ANY amount of items with the same speed.